# Telerik treeview bind to model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

How to set Telerik tree view bind to model? Is it possible to bind the root node and child node from same table? I am trying like follows:

```
@using edairy.Models
@model IEnumerable<MSEntities>
@(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
        .Name("TreeView1")
                    .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
        {
            mappings.For<MSM_PRODUCT>(binding => binding
                    .ItemDataBound((item, product) =>
                    {
                        item.Text = product.PRODUCT_CD;
                        item.Value = product.PRODUCT_DESC;
                        item.Expanded = true;
                    })
           .Children(product => product.MSM_PRODUCTS)
           );
```

but I am getting the error *sequence contain no elements*.

If I remove the `Children(product=>product.MSM_PRODUCTS)` line, it is executed and the product code is in nodes but I require child nodes. Also what can I do for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are doing this on the [Telerik Demo site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/databindingtomodel). Re-check your data. The treeview can do funny things if you have nulls for example.

Comment: In Telerik Demo Site in Controller part they return GetCategories() but i am not understanding what is in GetCategories().